# Buildfire: Widget showing error page when running the plugin locally

Tags: javascript

I was creating the plugin in Buildfire and when I run its instance locally I found the error page on widget control.

Comment: That's not how you should ask in order to get answers. Look at the help: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

I believe the behavior that you're describing was due to a bug in the SDK. If you get the latest version it should solve your issue

https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/releases/tag/1.8.1